# What is the best way to evenly spread a longitudinal line of SKSpriteNodes across the SKScene width?

Tags: skscene, vstack, hstack

**What is the best way to evenly spread a longitudinal line of `SKSpriteNodes` across the `SKScene's` width?**

Right now I have this group of `SKSpriteNodes` integrated in a `.sks` file. My goal is to have this group evenly distributed across the width of the `SKScene` every time the user rotates their iOS Device.

This `SKScene` has two vertical sections = the top section consisting of these `SKSpriteNodes` and a bottom section with other objects.

I have set `ourScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill` within my `showScene()` wherein I layout the "other objects" of the above bottom section.

Whether I use `.aspectFill` or `.resizeFill`, the result is the same = no spreading of these `SKSpriteNodes` wall-to-wall.

I have dived into `SwiftUI` with its `HStack` and `VStack` calls and this definitely works as advertised. **But**, I have trouble when I attempt to change `SKScenes` which don't apparently integrate with the stuff inherent to `HStack` and `VStack`.

In short, the top section with its `HStack` and `VStack` calls does not integrate with the bottom section into one `SKScene`.

I am left in a quandary and really need your guidance.